# How to restrict a java program to execute only N times

Tags: java

I want to make a java program that must run for a specific number of times only. e.g 2,5,10 etc. after that it must throw an Exception.

It is not allowed to use any FILE or Database for this. Someone gave me a hint of REGISTRY! But i don't know how to use it for this.
Please help me is this regard...

Comment: Is this for Windows only?  Because obviously, there's no Registry on Linux or OS X

Comment: Sounds like a copy protection scheme. You're doomed to fail.

Comment: Yes registry is windows file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use java preferences (registry on windows) :

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

You can find some sample usage here:

- http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter10/Preferences.html

Comment: Which is probably a file on non-Windows platforms. However, the application has to store the state somewhere!

Comment: Yeah, I don't see another solution !

Comment: Dear! will you please send ma simple code for this? a will be really thankful to you for this.

Comment: The only other solution I could see is to generate a GUID based on the system it's installed on, and ask for run-permission from a remote server.  But this would rely on a net connection.

Comment: Is java REGISTRY interface is not going to help me anymore in this regard?

Comment: @Arslan we are not here to do your homework ! check sample on the net: http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter10/Preferences.html

Comment: @tim_yates yes for sure remote server, or even local service keeping instance count in memory. so in both case need a second program/service.

Comment: Sir Sorry to say that i am not saying to do my home work. But i did not read about it before. I just want you to send few links of code in this regard... Or any example. Please if you have any.

Comment: sorry a bit nervous today ;-) ... see the second link I added in the answer, btw the Registry interface isn't going to help you.

Comment: Oh Thanks... Let me check it out!

Comment: @Alios Cochard! Your Link is really helpful for me. I just understand it. Now i am going to implement it in my application. Will Comment if Done!

Answer (score 4):

Whether this problem is solvable depends on what is meant by "any FILE or Database".

- Depending on your point of view, the Windows Registry is a kind of file / database.  Certainly, the only reason that values stay in the registry over a reboot is because registry changes are written to disc.
- You can move state (such as a count of the number of times an application has been run) to some other service on the local machine.  But once again, unless the service saves that state to disc (or some other stable storage medium) it will be lost is the local machine reboots.
- You can move state to a service on a remote machine, but once again it may be lost if not saved to disc, etc.  Moreover, you may not be able contact that remote service at the time you need the state; e.g. when starting the application.
- You can copy the state to lots of remote services without discs, but a network failure (or the user unplugging from the network) will stop you accessing the state.

So to summarize, if you cannot write to disc (or nvram, tape, etc) locally, you cannot guarantee that the counter won't get reset, and that it will be available when needed.  Therefore you cannot guarantee that the application won't be run more times than is allowed.

---

I imagine that you are trying to come up with some limited use scheme that users cannot subvert; e.g. by deleting stuff from the file / database / whatever that counter.  Unfortunately, unless you physically control BOTH the hardware AND the operating system on which the application runs, you cannot prevent someone from subverting any counter stored on the machine itself.  Anyone with "root" or full administrator rights, or with physical access, can ultimately change any data on the machine itself.

The best you can do is establish a secure connection to a remote server and use that to hold the usage counter.  But even that is futile, because a motivated person can reverse engineer the critical part of your application and disable the code that checks the counter.

Answer (score 0):

If the app. has a GUI, it can be launched using Java Web Start and use the PersistenceService.  Here is a small [demo. of the PersistenceService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).  The code is available for download.

Edit:
And the PersistenceService should work on any machine that has a JRE, as opposed to just Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this sounds like an attempt at copy protection, you may want to consider self-modifying code. There is an interesting discussion on this subject in Java here: [Self modifying code in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048496/self-modifying-code-in-java)