# Can programs write their own code?

Tags: java

I have noticed people speak about AI. My perception of A.I is code written such that a program can learn and simulate human behavior or even write its own code. I want to know if this can be done with java language on an IDE and if so an example code would be nice( code that can write its own code).

Comment: AI is not about code that modifies itself, it's rather about making programs that write other programs.

Comment: We all use code that writes code every day: the compiler. We write our code in a .NET language (or Java in your case) or whatever, then through some IL magic, we eventually get down to machine code. If the computer already knew what it *wanted* to do, that could just be another layer of abstraction on top of that, and that's not too difficult to imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in any general-purpose language; there is nothing inherent to a computer language which would make the resulting program either able or unable to "learn" because learining is a much higher-level concept.

Also note that learning is not exactly a clear-cut concept: any program whose behavior changes based on previous input could be argued to have "learnt" something.

Historically, LISP has been perceived as a language particularly well-suited for AI work, and indeed was the primary language of the AI movement of the '80s. An important reason for this is that it is particularly easy to make a program which writes LISP programs. This not to say that a Java program couldn't be made to do the same; it would just be far less convenient and require much more library support.

Answer (score 1):

What you refer to is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code and is not the same as AI. It was often used in the assembler days for performance optimization (for example removing a conditional statement after it is sure it will never be executed again) but I have never seen it used in Java, even thought it surely is possible. See also [Self modifying code in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048496/self-modifying-code-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). This branch of AI revolves around systems which learn from data given to them. If you really want to learn, there is a [course](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) available on machine learning on coursera.org.

Comment: -1 This doesn't provide an answer to OP's question.