# Is there a way to create methods within a method? Like coding to create code, but within the same code?

Tags: java, methods, types

Okay, so this is a bit complicated and I don't know that it will work but here is what I'm trying to see if is possible:

If I create a method in java, or write java code, can that method or code edit the whole body of code and depending on what is input to the method or code, create new methods or code within the code?

Like say for example I have a Test class. And then I create a method within the Test class.
In this method, I create and write some code that I try to create a method for in another class or within the Test class whichever is easier. Is this even possible? I don't think so, because when you run code, it seems like you cannot edit it while running, it basically runs all the code at the same time. I also wouldn't know how to get a data type (like int, double, String) that would be input that can be treated AS code itself.

If not this, then would I have to create code, that takes something as an input like say a string because idk how it would get something that could be treated as code itself, and then use that code to interact with another Java creating program, that would type whatever input as code, then run the other Java program? Would that work in a convoluted roundabout way? Thanks for reading all this, and hopefully someone has an answer.

This just came up to me, but CodingBat does something similar to this but idk how, and they use HTML so idk how applicable that would be.

Comment: I don't know if it can help you but I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485446/adding-new-method-to-a-class-through-reflection

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048496/self-modifying-code-in-java

Comment: Not intuitively.  This can be done in _[JavaScript](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)_, using the _eval_ function.

Comment: You are using the word “code” more than a dozen times without ever explaining what you mean with it. The Java compiler is a Java program creating “code” (class files) which can run as another program. You can also run the compiler from another program (guess what Eclipse, Netbeans, or IntelliJ do). And well, you can load freshly compiled classes into the already running environment, e.g. via class loaders. There’s no magic involved. In the end, “code” is a sequence of bytes, in a specific format, like anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, self-referential code is *extremely* frowned upon.

But, in the Java world, reflection has been built into the platform since (IIRC) v1.2, and enhancing or instrumenting code programmatically is quite well established.

It is quite accepted to use annotations (see Lombok) or interfaces (see Spring JPA repositories) to dynamically generate code, including methods. It could be very illuminating as a Java developer to see how these two very different frameworks do their thing.

Comment: Reflection had been added in Java 1.1.